# how to pop-out, pop-in iframes like Gmail hangout

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Pop-out a chat windows (using iframe) to new tab then pop-in it to get it back to the windows ..like Google does with they hangout chat windows in Gmail web.

I have been googling but could figure it out. Maybe my knowledge is not good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i mean that you want to say when you click in the arrow into the box, then is opening a popup with the chat.

I'm not sure that google do this, but is a way to do the same effect for the user.

When you click there, there open a pop up, the procediment to do this is the next;

you create a function in JS with `window.open()` this opens a window

If you want to open a page inside the window you have to specified it

`window.open("chat.php")`

the method open allows 3 parameters

`window.open(document,name of the window,attributes of the window)`

1. Document

   Uri of the doccument to be loaded into the popup.
2. Name of the window

   Identified for the window, you can do references to this id after is opened.
3. Attributes of the window

   A couple of name/value to assign different options for this widow, there are:

   - Width (of the window in pixels)
   - height (of the window in pixels)
   - top : position of the window starting on the top
   - left: position of the window starting on the left
   - toolbar, if you want to show the toolbar or not (`boolean`)
   - status, if you want to show the status bar (`boolean`)
   - location, if you want to show the location bar.
   - directories, if you want to show the personal bar.
   - scrollbars, if you want to show the scrollbar
   - menubar if you want to show the menubar

this is a example of how to open a new window :

```
function openPopUp(){
     newpopup = window.open('chat.html/user1=xxxx?user2=yyyy','newwindow','width=300, height=400')
}
```

the back-end of this page is going to load the chat between the user 1 and 2.

now to go back to the parent window.

you can return a value then when you click in the arrow to go back, they should be something in the `onclick` function like

```
function returnPopUp(){
    top.close();
    return "user1=xxxx?user2=yyyy"
}
```

then they load the frame in the parent window again.

and as I told you before, something similar for the `newpopup` close listener.

Thanks.